# cv2 triangulatePoints always returns same Z value

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, camera-calibration, triangulation

I am trying to get 3D points using cv2.triangulatePoints but it always returns almost same Z value. My output looks like this: [image: output image and output 3d points] As it seen, all points are in almost same Z value. There is no depth.

Here is my triangulation:

```
    def triangulate(self, proj_mat1, pts0, pts1):
        proj_mat0 = np.zeros((3,4))
        proj_mat0[:, :3] = np.eye(3)
        pts0, pts1 = self.normalize(pts0), self.normalize(pts1) 
        pts4d = cv2.triangulatePoints(proj_mat0, proj_mat1, pts0.T, pts1.T).T
        pts4d /= pts4d[:, 3:]
        out = np.delete(pts4d, 3, 1)
        print(out)
        return out
```

Here is my projection matrix calculation:

```
    def getP(self, rmat, tvec):
       P = np.concatenate([rmat, tvec.reshape(3, 1)], axis = 1)
       return P
```

Here is the part that I get rmat, tvec and call triangulation:

```
    E, mask = cv2.findEssentialMat(np.array(aa), np.array(bb), self.K)
    _, R, t, mask = cv2.recoverPose(E, np.array(aa), np.array(bb), self.K)
    proj_mat1 = self.getP(R, t)
    out = self.triangulate(proj_mat1, np.array(aa, dtype = np.float32), np.array(bb, dtype = np.float32))
```

My camera matrix:

```
array([[787.8113353 ,   0.        , 318.49905794],
       [  0.        , 786.9638204 , 245.98673477],
       [  0.        ,   0.        ,   1.        ]])
```

My projection matrix 1:

```
array([[1., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 1., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 1., 0.]])
```

Explanations:

- aa and bb are matched points from 2 frames.
- self.K is my camera matrix
- rotation and translation matrices are extracted from Essential matrix
- Essential matrix calculated from matched keypoints. It changes every frame.
- Projection matrix 2 changes every frame.

Output after changing first projection matrix (I switched from matplotlib to pangolin as 3D visualization tool): [image: output]

Output after using P1 and P2 that I mentioned in comments: [image]

Where is my mistake? Please let me know if any further information needed. I will update my question.

Comment: ciao! I think that in order to help people understand the maths behind your code it would be good if you can add at the end of your question all the calculated matrices: camera matrix, rotation matrix, translation vector, projection matrix 1 and 2, projection points arrays aa and bb and anything else in this sense... good luck!

Comment: Thanks for your comment @Antonino. I edited my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you so much for all the effort @Antonino. My webcams were pretty bad. After changing every part of my code and making many trials I decided to change my webcams and bought good webcams. It worked :D Here is the result:
[image]

Comment: that's very good news, I'm happy for you! just out of curiosity: did you have to change anything in the initial code you posted [e.g. the `proj_mat0` values] or did it work out of the box as it was originally posted?

Comment: I only found new camera matrix with chessboard technique. Other than that I did not change anything. I can share my full code if you want to take a look.

Comment: thanks a lot for your reply! no, I just wanted to understand if you had to change something under a theoretical/mathematical point of view... good luck with your project mate!

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately I don't have the possibility to double-check directly but my gut feeling is that the issues you are facing are essentially due to the choice of your first projection matrix

I did some research and I found [this great paper](https://eec284.weebly.com/uploads/1/0/0/5/10052112/report.pdf) with both theory and practice. Despite differing a little bit from your approach, there is a thing that is worth saying

If you check carefully, the first projection matrix is exactly the camera matrix with an additional last column equal to zero. In fact, the rotation matrix for the first camera reduces to the identity matrix and the corresponding translation vector is a null vector, so using [this general formula](https://answers.opencv.org/question/13545/how-to-obtain-projection-matrix/):

```
P = KT
```

where `P` is the projection matrix, `K` the camera matrix and `T` the matrix obtained by the rotation matrix `R` flanked by the translation vector `t` according to:

```
T = [R|t]
```

then you will get:

[image: matrices_multiplication]

Coming back to your case, first of all I would suggest to change your first projection matrix as just said

Also, I understand that you are planned to work with something different at every frame but if after the suggested change the things still don't match then in your shoes I'd start working with just 2 images [I think you implicitly did already to create the correspondence between `aa` and `bb`], calculating first the matrices with your algorithm and then checking with the ones obtained following the article above

In this way you would be able to understand/debug which matrices are creating you troubles

Comment: I tried changing the first projection matrix to K * [R|t] as you suggest. I ended up with a straight line. I added output to the end of my question.

Comment: @MertcanKarık sorry, my bad in the explanation! In the case of your code I would replace `proj_mat0`, not `proj_mat1` [I was working with projection matrix 1 and projection matrix 2, as in the linked article and OpenCV documentation]

Comment: By "first" I meant [proj_mat0]. I normalize them to see near to origin in 3D visualization. If I don't normalize I see the exact same thing in another location. [.T] means transpose. I transpose [pts0] and [pts1] because [cv2.triangulatePoints] accepts [2xN] array as points. For your last question, I only changed [proj_mat0].

Comment: Also, I tried this too: I get camera matrix and distortion coefficients using [cv2.calibrateCamera], then using them, I found the rotation matrix and translation vector with [cv2.stereoCalibrate]. And finally using camera matrices, distortion coefficients, the rotation matrix, and translation vector I found [P1], [P2] matrices with [cv2.stereoRectify]. Then instead of [proj_mat0] and [proj_mat1] I used P1 and P2 in triangulation but the output was bad again. I added output to end of my question.

Comment: @MertcanKarık interesting! check [this project](https://github.com/uoip/stereo_ptam) and in particular the `triangulate_points` method inside components.py: the programmer here uses an identical style for calling the opencv `triangulatePoints` method, so you can check how he builds the values to be passed to that function. Once you double check the correctness of your input values maybe you can use that code to build the output and cross-check it with yours